# How can I enumerate only certain subsections?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, sections-paragraphs

I want to show serial number 1. 2. or 1) 2) only before BB like the figure shows. I don't want to use ways like this `\subsection{1.BB}`,  `\subsection{2.BB}`. Is there a smart way?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,natbib]{apa6}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multirow}

\title{AAA}
\shorttitle{AAA}

\begin{document}
\section{A}
\subsection{AA}
AAA
\subsection{AA}
AAA
\section{B}
\subsection{BB}
BBB
\subsection{BB}
BBB
\section{C}
\subsection{CC}
CCC
\subsection{CC}
CCC

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjust `secnumdepth` and the subsection counter display `\thesubsection` at the appropriate locations:

[image]

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}

\title{AAA}
\shorttitle{AAA}

% Remove \thesection from \thesubsection
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}% Default \thesection.\arabic{subsection}

\begin{document}
\section{A}
\subsection{AA}
AAA
\subsection{AA}
AAA
\section{B}

% Display subsection counters and above
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\subsection{BB}
BBB
\subsection{BB}
BBB

% Display only chapter counters and above
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\section{C}
\subsection{CC}
CCC
\subsection{CC}
CCC

\end{document}
```

Comment: this won't persist into a table of contents.  (although the original question didn't mention whether a toc would be involved.)

Comment: Werner, thank you so much for detailed explanation. That solves my problem!